# Subdomains as a hosting server and SEO

Tags: seo, hosting, subdomain

We have a website site.com and want to give faster access to that site to users from other countries. Idea is to have a hosting in each continent and redirect to that hosting by GeoIP such as: eu.site.com - Europe, us.site.com - North America, au.site.com - Australia, etc.
Each of that sites will have exactly the same content and files, so eu.site.com/fr will display exactly the same content as au.site.com/fr

Question is how it will affect Page Ranking and SEO in general.

site.fr, site.au, site.uk - too difficult to manage, so it's not acceptable.

fr.site.com, au.site.com, uk.site.com - the same problem.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is duplicate content and considered low quality by Google. This is the kind of content the [Panda algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Panda) is weeding out of their search results. What you need to do is pick a primary domain to be shown in Google's search results and then use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) for the rest of the websites. Then after the visitor has visited that main website you can detect their location and redirect them to their local site.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong. All users goes to site.com/page_name, where we generate <link rel="canonical" href="site.com/page_name"; /> then by their IP I redirect them to eu.site.com/page_name or au.site.com/page_name